# how button can be address on annotationView to perform an action in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, button, annotations, mkmapview

I want to add button in annotationView in mapkit in iphone for performing an action on clicking that button. How can i perform action on clicking that button? i also dont able to add button in annotation view using the following code:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil; 
    if(annotation != mapView.userLocation) 
    {
    static NSString *defaultPinID = @"com.invasivecode.pin";
        pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if ( pinView == nil )
            pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];

        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed; 
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        pinView.animatesDrop = YES;

        UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = infoButton;

    } 
    else {
        [mapView.userLocation setTitle:@"I am here"];
    }
    return pinView;
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how can i add button to the default userlocation's blue dot's  annotation view? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding the button in default blue dot's annotationView, use the delegate method and add button there in following way:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
if (!view.rightCalloutAccessoryView) {

    UIButton *detailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = detailButton;

    detailButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44);
    detailButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop;
    detailButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;

 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I used

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)eMapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
```

to capture the button press.

And I created the button like this:

```
UIButton *detailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
detailButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44);
detailButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop;
detailButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = detailButton;
```

in

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv viewForAnnotation: (id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

Comment: what you write in calloutAccessoryControlTapped:  ??/

Comment: In my case I only checked that the view was the kind of class that is my custom MKAnnotationView and then push a new view controller on my navigationcontroller. It's totally up to you what you want to do in there.

Answer (score 1):

Just look at my code sample :

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView1 viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{   
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    TagMark * tempMark = (TagMark *) annotation;

    MKPinAnnotationView *dropPin=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"venues"];

    dropPin.animatesDrop = YES;
    dropPin.canShowCallout = YES;

    UIButton *pinButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    pinButton.frame = CGRectMake(2, 2, 28, 29);
    [pinButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ph.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    pinButton.tag = [[tempMark useID] intValue];
    [pinButton addTarget:self action:@selector(makeCall:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    dropPin.rightCalloutAccessoryView=pinButton; 

    return dropPin;
}
```

Hope it helps you...

Comment: if possible can u please show me the TagMark.m...or can mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped: delegate method be used for it...if used please show me....thanks in advance...